# Add and subtract values from a single array Java

Tags: java, arrays, addition, subtraction

I am having trouble subtracting values from a single array. If I have the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 stored in an array, how can I find the difference?

For example `1-2-3-4-5 = -13`

I know how to sum the values of an array but having trouble subtracting one array element from the next to get the correct answer.

int sum = 0;

```
if (operator == '+'){
  for ( int j = 0; j < intArray.length; j++ ) {
    sum += intArray[j]; 
  }
}
if (operator == '-'){
  for ( int j = 0; j < intArray.length; j++ ) {
    sum += intArray[j] - intArray[j+1] ; 
  }
}

System.out.println("The answer is " + sum);
```

Comment: Have you tried using "-=" instead of "+="?

Comment: Your example gives special treatment to the first element. Is that right? Did you mean 1-2-3-4-5? Or did you mean -1-2-3-4-5  (starting with the first element vs. starting with 0)?

Answer (score 2):

//This is a pretty simple way to solve it

```
public class Minimize {

        public static int substractArrayValues(int [] q){
            int val=0;
            for (int i=0; i<q.length; i++){

                if (i==0){
                    val=q[i];
                }
                else {
                    val=val-q[i];
                }
            }
            return val;

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int [] q={1,2,3,4,5};

            System.out.println(substractArrayValues(q));
        }

    }
```

This will print -13

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to subtract 1-2-3-4-5 which is equal to -13.

So here comes your mistake `sum+=intArray[j] - intArray[j+1] ;`

Operation:-

```
         Iteration 1:- sum=-1       which is     (1-2)       sum=-1

         Iteration 2:sum=sum+(2-3)  which is     (-1+2-3)    sum=-2

         Iteration 3:sum=sum+(3-4)  which is     (-2+3-4)    sum=-3

         Iteration 4:sum=sum+(4-5)  which is     (-3+4-5)    sum=-4

         Iteration 5:sum=sum+(5-Garbage value or indexoutofbound exception)         
          sum=garbage value
```

Try using `sum-=intArray[j];`

Answer (score 1):

With `IntStream` and a bit of functional programming

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
int myArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int sum = IntStream
          // get all the indices
          .range(0, myArray.length) 

          // for the 1st element use the +ve sign 
          // and for the rest use -ve sign: so it 
          // will generate 1,-2,-3,-4,-5
          .map(i -> i == 0? myArray[i] : -myArray[i]) 

          // add the generated elements using map: 1-2-3-4-5
          .sum(); 

System.out.println(sum); // -13
```

Comment: @soundslikeodd added exlanation, hope that makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with a the sum at index 0 and then call -= to all the other elements. currently you are doing index - (index -1) which will fail since you don't check for out of bounds. Also the math will be wrong in your current implementation because you use values to subtract twice instead on once.

Take this array with your subtraction method A[1, 2, 3, 4]

```
sum = 0;
sum += 1 - 2;
sum is -1; (Correct)
sum += 2 - 3;
sum is (-1 + -1) = -2 (Wong, should be -4)
sum += 3 - 4;
sum is (-2 - 1) = -3 (Wrong should be -8)
sum += 4 - A[4] (ERROR index out of bounds)
```

Here is the implementation that subtracts the values once

```
if (operator == '-'){
  sum = intArray.length > 0 ? intArray[0] : 0;
  for ( int j = 1; j < intArray.length; j++ ) {
    sum -= intArray[j]; 
  }
}
```

Comment: i was in the middle of explaining it @soundslikeodd

Answer (score 0):

You always do a positive sum `+=` on operator `-`.
But how about using the [`Stream`-API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) instead?

```
IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
         .reduce(operatorFunction('-'))
         .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

with the following [`IntBinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html)-returning function:

```
static IntBinaryOperator operatorFunction(char operator) {
  if (operator == '-') {
    return (int1, int2) -> int1 - int2;
  }
  return (int1, int2) -> int1 + int2;
}
```

which prints `-13` as you would expect. This is all you need. Note that you could also use `IntStream.sum` to achieve a simple sum. With the `operatorFunction` however you could also add `*` or `÷` later if you wish.

Another way to write the above code (with intermediate values):

```
int[] yourInputArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
char operator = '-';
OptionalInt = Stream.of(yourInputArray)
                    .reduce(operatorFunction(operator));
```

From here you can call `orElse(0)` or throw an exception with `orElseThrow(() -> ...)`, etc. Just have a look at the [`OptionalInt`-javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html) for your options. As soon as you move away from the primitive `int` you may want to exchange the code by using [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), [`BinaryOperator<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) and [`Optional<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

By the way, there is also an `IndexOutOfBoundException` in your current code. But why messing with indexes and arrays, if you can use `Stream`s and so few lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

We have to take the first value in the array, and then subtract or add the remaining values from and to it depending on the operator. This is done as shown below:

```
int sum, dif;
if(intArray.length >= 1){
  sum = intArray[0];
  dif = intArray[0];
}
if (operator == '+'){
   if(intArray.length > 1){
     for ( int j = 1; j < intArray.length; j++ ) {
       sum += intArray[j]; 
     }
   }
   System.out.println("The sum is = " + sum);
}
if (operator == '-'){
  if(intArray.length > 1){
    for ( int j = 1; j < intArray.length; j++ ) {
      dif -= intArray[j]; 
    }
  }
  System.out.println("The difference is = " + dif);
}
```